Erlang/OTP with elixir fails
I am trying to set elixir up as a back-end for React, and I have done a bunch of stuff to get it running. I cannot seem to make it work.
"10:09:43.125 [error] beam/beam_load.c(206): Error loading module 'Elixir.Hex':
  This BEAM file was compiled for an old version of the runtime system.
  To fix this, please re-compile this module with Erlang/OTP 24 or later."

I have tried sudo apt-get install erlang and mix deps.compile or mix compile or mix clean

Try https://elixirforum.com/t/creating-an-elixir-project-generates-error-beam-beam-load-c-148-error-loading-module-elixir-hex/54122

Most elixir devs I know use asdf or mise for installing elixir, erlang and other stuff. I recommend starting with asdf.  https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiShdXyo8SGAxWETEEAHU3dAEwQFnoECAEQDQ&usg=AOvVaw1Lon6MY2v6jWTJMCVx229b
When it is installed, you can asdf plugin add erlang and asdf install erlang 26, etc.
On an existing elixir project, you may see a .tool-versions file. This is for asdf to use. asdf intall will find the .tool-versions file. The file is created when you run asdf local...

Have you tried to run mix local.hex

You should use asdf to install elixir and erlang. The main props I can see of using asdf is that you can select any version of the language
